# Audio to hifi with a usb input

Tags: audio

My TEAC hifi has a usb input.  I have prevously used a USB key with mp3's to play music fro the flash drive.

Does anyone have an idea if it is possible to stream music from the pi running raspbmc ( brillant, btw!) to this usb  input?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The short answer is no, since the Pi works as a USB host, and cannot be connected as an USB device ("slave"). The micro-USB port on the Pi is for power only, and doesn't connect the data lines.

The [more complex answer](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/5229/2972) is that hardware-wise, model A of the Raspberry could work as an USB device, connected through what is normally it's host USB port. Model B is wired differently, with an USB hub, and cannot work as a host.
See [this thread](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/5229/2972) on the Raspberry forum. Anyway, there are no drivers for this functionality yet.

Comment: Thanks - just learned something about the dual modes of USB ports!