# Raspberry Pi as a link between a scanner and cloud storage

Tags: usb, wifi, noobs, storage

I've never had a Raspberry Pi in my hands. I'm just looking for a device to perform a specific single task and I wonder if Raspberry Pi could be my solution.

My situation is this: I've got a portable scanner with USB port. One button allows to scan a document directly to a flashdrive connected to this port. What I want to do is to connect Raspberry Pi instead of a flashdrive to USB port in the hope that it would automatically send recieved files to cloud storage (for ex. dropbox) via wifi.

It's very important that it would do it automatically. The device must be configured once and have no need to connect keyboard, mouse or monitor ever since. It would be switched off daily so it must also boot up without the need for user interference and go to a state that allows recieving and sending files to cloud automatically.

Is this possible to achieve with Raspberry Pi?

Comment: I'm interested in knowing why you think others would know the capabilities of an unspecified scanner?

Comment: Scanner capabilities don't matter in this case. The only important thing is that it saves files to a specified folder on flashdrive when the button is clicked.

Comment: My mistake.  I misunderstood what you meant by connect Raspberry Pi rather than flashdrive.

Comment: I've edited the question a bit so there will be less trouble understanding my poor English.

Comment: No need, your English was perfect, it was my understanding that was at fault!

Comment: Does the scanner have a device USB port too? I.e. can it be connected to a computer? If so, it might be possible to use the Pi as a host, wire a button to the GPIO pins, and have the Pi scan a document when the button is pressed. Check if [sane](http://www.sane-project.org/) has support for your scanner.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Pi cannot be used as a USB device only as a host. This has been discussed here with various workarounds
[Can I use Raspberry Pi as a USB peripheral device?](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/271/can-i-use-raspberry-pi-as-a-usb-peripheral-device)

I wonder if you could modify an eye-fi to connect to dropbox
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eye-Fi
all you would need in addition to the eye-fi was a  basic usb sd card reader.

Comment: So it would be something like that:
scanner->{USB}>card-reader>eyefi>{wifi}>raspberry-pi>{wifi}>cloud , right? I think that could work. Thx.
I still hope to find a little less complicated solution as I need to do around a houndred such installations.

Comment: you may not need the pi in that equation, I know there have been eye-fi hacks, but I do not know if it can talk directly with dropbox.

Comment: I couldn't find a solution that would link Eye-Fi directly to dropbox, but combination with RPi should work, so I think I'll go with that. Thanks again.