# Does the Pi Zero have two OTG USB ports (data over PWR IN)?

Tags: pi-zero

[This answer](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/40626/54372) claims that both micro USB ports of the Raspberry Pi Zero can be used for OTG and that the `PWR IN` connector supports data transfer. As much as I want that to be true, I can't find a single other resource supporting this claim.

To the contrary:

- [these](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/271/can-i-use-raspberry-pi-as-a-usb-peripheral-device) [answers](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/8587/can-you-transfer-data-through-the-microusb) explain that the Pi A/B do not support OTG over the power port because data pins are unconnected; presumably the same is true for the Pi Zero?
- in [this thread](https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?f=63&t=127116) at the Pi Forums, user `rpdom` states:

  > You can't kill the Zero by plugging the power into the data USB socket. It will work fine like that. You can't use the power socket for data though.

So, is it true or false the `PWR IN` port supports data transfer? Please don't respond without details and evidence to back up your answer.

---

*I expect the answer is 'of course not' but I would love to be surprised. And, yes, I plan to fix that one answer if/when it's proven wrong.*

*Edited to clarify title*

Comment: Hmm. I just plugged a cut, stripped micro USB cable into each port and did some continuity testing. I'd hoped to see the data lines on the power socket tied together or perhaps connected to ground. No dice there unfortunately - nothing's connected to anything else. The best evidence I can come up with that there's no data connectivity on the power socket is circumstantial: [there are test pads](http://hackers.gallery/841/misc/raspberry-pi-zero-pad-probing) for D+ (PP22) and D- (PP23) on the USB socket, and none for the power socket.

Comment: I think the source of the contrary information ("this answer", which was perhaps upvoted just for *appearing* coherent and researched) is singular, and if you look through the references they do not support the claims.  Put another way, there may be only one person on the planet who has said this and it is most likely because of his own misunderstanding.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> So, is it true or false the PWR IN port supports data transfer?

As you and others here have indicated, false.

> Please don't respond without details and evidence to back up your
>   answer.

- [Raspberry Pi Zero V1.3 schematics](https://github.com/raspberrypi/documentation/blob/master/hardware/raspberrypi/schematics/rpi_SCH_Zero_1p3_reduced.pdf)

You can see that the micro-USB port in the top left has no lines for USB data, while the one on the bottom row has OTG support.