# Java, the RaspberryPi Zero and its USB port

Tags: usb, serial, pi-zero, java

I will be getting my RaspberryPi Zero tomorrow and I wanted to use it in combination with the RFID-RC522 module as some sort of USB-RFID-Tag-Reader.

This works with the RaspberryPi 3 Model B I own (over a network-socket instead of USB), but since the Zero is lacking a LAN / WLAN Interface and I didn't quite find anything useful on a Java Socket equivalent which uses USB or, more specifically, serial communcation with the Zero over its USB port with java, I thought I would ask the question here.

Thanks a bunch,
rocket_doge_

Comment: Do you want to use the Pi Zero as a USB device (connecting it to a "real" computer)? How do you connect the RC522 to the pi?

Comment: @Bex I want to use the RasPi as a USB device on e.g. my Laptop / PC and I connect the RC522 over the GPIO pins / SPI

Answer (score 1):

This sounds like a very interesting and educating project!

Sadly, what you want to do is probably not as easy as you would like. USB is a complex protocol, and not as high-level as network sockets. Java does not support it very well, and while you could write a minimal custom driver and interface to that through java, it would be easier just scrapping the java part altogether.

Have a look here for how to use Pi Zero as a device: [Can the Pi Zero act as an USB peripheral device?](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/38576/can-the-pi-zero-act-as-an-usb-peripheral-device/40626#40626)

Or add networking to your pi zero: [What's the cheapest way to get network connectivity to the Pi Zero?](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/38622/whats-the-cheapest-way-to-get-network-connectivity-to-the-pi-zero)

If you want to make a "device" out of the pi, you want to make what in linux-lingo is called a "gadget driver". (The *device* driver is on the host machine, talking to the device. The *gadget* driver is the sw on the device that the *device* driver talks to.)

To write a gadget driver, start out at http://www.linux-usb.org/gadget/. It seems ADA Fruit has a tutorial about how to make a serial or an ethernet gadget: https://learn.adafruit.com/turning-your-raspberry-pi-zero-into-a-usb-gadget/overview

You would want to go on, to create a custom type of gadget, with a custom device driver, that loads when your gadget is detected. From there, you could do an interrupt type USB-channel, that tells the host system when there has been an event on the gadget.

So, on the pi zero, you would build a gadget driver, and on the host you would make a device driver.

If you want to go ahead with this, you should have a look at [the horse book](https://lwn.net/Kernel/LDD3/).

Comment: If it is connected as an ethernet device (which is probably the most useful way to go), then it will have an IP address and you can connect to it using a normal network socket, etc.

Comment: Thank you very much ^.^ I initially thought about putting the thing into my laptop so I could login and secure passwords with an RFID tag (theres some space in the case left) but I guess I will have to scrap that idea. Just out of interest; what would I need for the custom driver / interface part?

Comment: *"what would I need for the custom driver / interface part"* -> A few textbooks for starters (such as LDD3), and it is a C only realm...

Comment: @goldilocks LDD3 == "the horse book". ;)

Comment: Oh I thought [you meant this](http://us.macmillan.com/thehorse/wendywilliams). ;]  Actually I had not heard it called the horse book before but I have a paper copy and I think I understand why.  I have a paper copy of the dragon book too but there is no dragon on it :(

Comment: TBH I doubt there is much to be gained writing some special USB driver here vs. just using a network socket on the ethernet link. I haven't tested to see how much bandwidth is actually available, I don't know if it is arbitrary more limited that what it could provide.