# Is communication between Raspeberry Pi 2 and smartphone possible using USB

Tags: pi-2, usb, communication

I'm currently trying to make a communication between my Raspberry Pi 2 and my smartphone (Samsung Galaxy S7). 
I'd like to do it using a USB cable, does anyone know if it's possible and how to do it?

Answer (score 1):

I think in effect you're asking if the Pi can support USB host mode (a.k.a. On-The-Go or OTG).  From reading assorted posts, I gather that you can't do this with any of the Pis that have built-in Ethernet (which is provided with a chip that sits on the internal USB and somehow this prevents host mode from being used).

The Pi A and the Pi Zero (but probably not Zero W) apparently can be used this way, but apparently not any of the others.

I'd provide links but I didn't find any that were clear enough to include here. Googling for "raspberry pi host mode" will find most of the same stuff I read. [Another question](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/271/can-i-use-raspberry-pi-as-a-usb-peripheral-device) has relevant answers though.

Answer (score 1):

### MTP

If you want to copy files to and from your smartphone's storage, you need to install an MTP program (either a commandline tool or a graphical file browser) on your Raspberry Pi.

---

### Easy Way

One graphical program that's easy to use is `nautilus`.  It's a file browser with a lot of dependencies, so it might take awhile to install, but it's intuitive.

---

### Hard(er) Way

If you're running Raspbian Linux, [these instructions for Debian Linux](https://wiki.debian.org/mtp) should work.  Basically:

1. Install `mtp-tools`
2. Run `mtp-detect` (it should see your phone)
3. Run `fusermount -u /path/to/emptyfolder`
4. Run `jmtpfs -l` (it should see your phone)
5. Run `jmtpfs /path/to/emptyfolder`

Now you should be able to see all of your phone's files in `emptyfolder`!